# Join in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to make a query where I get the number of comments on a News in a row in laravel.

[News Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2aP7.png)
[News_Comments Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWAZB.png)

[Display count of comments in 'Kommentare'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsxVx.png)

This is the query in mysql.

```
SELECT news.Id,news.title,news.body,news.created_at, COUNT(news_comments.id) AS Kommentare
FROM news
LEFT JOIN news_comments ON news_comments.fk_news_id = news.id
GROUP BY news.id
```

[Result of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOPNP.png)

How would I write that in laravel 5.5?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not in images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the relationship between News and NewsComments.
In News Model, supposing that `news_comments` is in `NewsComment` Model, in App folder. Set the relationship:

```
public function newsComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\NewsComment', 'fk_news_id');
}
```

And then, to get the count, you can use `count()` method:

```
$count = $news->newsComments()->count();
```

Or, directly using blade:

```
{{ $news->newsComments()->count() }}
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make a model for news table name `News` and another for comments table name `Comment`. And then in your News model, define a `hasMany()` relationship method like -

```
public function comments(){
       return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

And then in your controller, retrieve like this-

```
$newses = News::with('comments')->get();
```

This will load `all` news with `corresponding` all comments. If you want to load `single` news with `all` comments then -

```
$news  = News::with('comments')->where('id',$news_id)->first();
```

To get the comment `count`, you can `count()` on relationship like -

```
$count = News::find($news_id)->comments()->count();
```

Comment: I just tried that, too. Working perfectly fine, helped me a lot!!! Thank you for your time.

Comment: @pyth welcome :)

Comment: Just a question for a better understanding. I have in my news_comments table an author_id that is related to the users table. 
Is it literally the same approach, just ->hasMany to ->hasOne?
Then whenever I access the news_comment model i have automatically access to the corresponding user?

Comment: Ok, I did it but with belongsTo, i need to check when to use what. Thanks.

Comment: yes, almost same but used belongsTo rather than has one